# Is it possible to display own string in taskbar calendar in windows?

Tags: windows

Currently calendar in my taskbar looks like:

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJht5.png)

I want windows to display my own string (in taskbar calendar) instead of the year for eg.:

> 23:11 foo/02/28

How to do that? I'm using windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured out that in calendar settings I had to wrote:

> 'foo'/MM/dd